# How to save and parse XML UTF-8 (Ü,Ä,Ö) correctly in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, utf-8, xml-parsing

**1. BASED ON**

My code is based on this Tutorial here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40mYDQkK44A
https://github.com/FoamyGuy/StackSites

So if you're trying to understand what's happening, just look at the whole Code there, I haven't changed a lot in it.

**2. MY XML**

```
    <event>
    <name>Reunion</name>
    <date>Freitag 07.07.2017 </date>
    <link>EVENT LINK</link>
    <about>Über eine Woche ist es her, seit .... ÄÜÖ :-) </about>
    <image>IMAGE LINK</image>
</event>
```

**3. DOWNLOAD of the XML**

```
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
    /************************************************
     * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
     ************************************************/
    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
     /************************************************
     * Define OutputStreams to write to our file.
     ************************************************/

    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    //long total = 0;
    int count;
    //loop and read the current chunk

    while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
        //keep track of size for progress.
        //total += count;

        //write this chunk
        bos.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    //Have to call flush or the  file can get corrupted.
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
```

**4. Reading the XML**

```
        // Get our factory and PullParser
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        // Open up InputStream and Reader of our file.
        FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput("Events.xml");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8"));


        // point the parser to our file.
        xpp.setInput(reader);

        // get initial eventType
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        // Loop through pull events until we reach END_DOCUMENT
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            // Get the current tag
            String tagname = xpp.getName();

            // React to different event types appropriately
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SITE)) {
                        // If we are starting a new <site> block we need
                        //a new StackSite object to represent it
                        curStackSite = new StackSite();

                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    //grab the current text so we can use it in END_TAG event
                    curText = xpp.getText();

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_EVENT)) {
                        // if </event> then we are done with current Event
                        // add it to the list.
                        stackSites.add(curStackSite);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_NAME)) {
                        // if </name> use setName() on curSite
                        curStackSite.setName(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_LINK)) {
                        // if </link> use setLink() on curSite
                        curStackSite.setLink(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_ABOUT)) {
                        // if </about> use setAbout() on curSite
                        curStackSite.setAbout(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_IMAGE_URL)) {
                        // if </image> use setImgUrl() on curSite
                        curStackSite.setImgUrl(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_DATE)) {
                        // if </date> use setDate() on curSite
                        curStackSite.setDate(curText);
                    }
                    break;
```

**5. My Question**

Basically everything in this code is working like it should, except displaying Characters like "Ö,Ä,Ü" in the TextView. The TextView is always giving me a "?" instead of a "Ü,Ä,..". So I tried fixing this in every single way Google fed me with, but I can't get around this problem.

I tried changing the buffer "byte data[] = new byte[1024];" to something bigger, instead of the BufferedInputStream I tried InputStreamReader ecc.

What I observed is that: saving my XML with Notepad in "ANSI"-Code does work fine, saving it with "UTF-8" doesn't work at all, I'm getting nothing from my reader.

I also wanted to display some emojis, but that's the second part of the problem.. getting "Ü,Ä,Ö" displayed would be more important first of all.

**Display / Layout**

Here is my XML File of the displaying Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/schalt2"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    >

    <ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/iconImg"

    />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/event_title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/iconImg"
    />

    <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/event_date"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_below="@id/event_title"/>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/eventdescriptlong"
    android:layout_below="@id/event_title"
    android:padding="28dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />
```

So if I'm trying to use a TextView like this:

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/eventdescriptlong"
    android:layout_below="@id/event_title"
    android:text="ÜÖÄ"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />
```

It get's displayed correctly.

Comment: What about the codepage of the displaying components?

Comment: Thank you for your time - the displaying takes places in this two files: https://github.com/FoamyGuy/StackSites/blob/master/src/com/makemyandroidapp/example/stacksites/StackSite.java  AND https://github.com/FoamyGuy/StackSites/blob/master/src/com/makemyandroidapp/example/stacksites/SitesAdapter.java

Comment: I was referring to your layout XML, especially the fonts used by the `TextView`s...

Comment: I edited my post with the XML File, hope this helps you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, the problem is the following:

Saving the File in UTF-8 Charset, parsing it locally does add this 3 bytes in front of the XML

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7uqI.png[enter image description here][1]

So you absolutely need to add this line:
            fis.skip(3);

Hope this helps you guys :)